# File content into windows variable - PowerShell

Tags: linux, windows, powershell

I'm new in PowerShell, I want to put the content of a file into a windows variable.

In fact I need the equivalent of those linux commans on windows

```
testvar=$(cat test.txt)
echo $testvar
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, because `cat` and `echo` are aliased to `Get-Content` and `Write-Output` respectively, that code will work, though you need to prefix `testvar` with a `$`, so it reads `$testvar`. It can also be written with proper cmdlets and remove the unnecessary subexpression:

```
$testvar = Get-Content test.txt
Write-Output $testvar
```

And you really don't need to use `Write-Output`, either. simply writing `$testvar` on its own will default to the output stream.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the code I provided above is how you do this from PowerShell. Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
$testvar = Get-Content "test.txt"
Write-Host $testvar
```

cat is an alias in powershell to Get-Content,
echo is an alias to Write-Output